# Screen Just blank when selecting "install elementary os"

Tags: boot, grub

Screen Just blank when selecting "install elementary os" in EFi mode, when i try to install from bios mode just the white courser is blinking.

Answer (score 1):

often this can be fixed by editing the boot options. When you are on the screen that lets you select try or install you can hit a button to edit the options. I believe it is "e" you need to press. look for a line that says "quite splash" add "nomodeset" then hit f10 or enter or whatever the screen says to hit to boot.

nomodeset keeps the kernel from controlling graphics card settings and lets the xorg do it instead. It will probably let you boot up and install, but you'll want to figure out how to boot without it after you install because it makes your graphics run slower.